# Customize the style of two listboxes one inside the other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have two listboxes, one inside the other.

I have this xaml code to bind listbox to a List. I would like to know if is possible to change this:

[image]

to this :

[image]

Is it possible to keep the property of the second listbox disabled? This is my xaml code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" x:Name="MyList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" AlternationCount="2">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action OpenItem($dataContext)]"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFEFEF" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="8"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Date operation" /> - <Run Text="{Binding Data}" /></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

                    <ListBox Height="auto" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondList}" Margin="8" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Inxex}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Is this issue present only when you select an item (which changes the background color)?

Comment: Yes when i select an item of first listbox,  the background of the second listbox is grey. i would like that is blue as if it were a single listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to set `ItemContainerStyle` on the inner list box. In the style you'd need to set the template to:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ContentPresenter/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

That's the bare-bones template that will conform to design above. If you need selection for inner items then surround ContentPresenter with a `Border` set it's background to transparent and then control the background with triggers.

### EDIT

This is the full style for inner item with selection:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I see. Could you show me the entire part of the code to change? thankyou

Comment: Added a full style for inner item.